# Which is the best way or the best practice to custom a corpus for a chatterbot?

Tags: python, chatbot, training-data, corpus, chatterbot

We have been creating a chat-bot for users that need to create requests and track issues, relating with a service.

We´ve been making some tests with the chatbot's intelligence, with a 800k registers data, also i'm creating and duplicating lines with many different requesting way of asking.

There are 2 kinds of issues:

-Due this amount of of registers with the same answer in our corpus, the single result answer that we got, is completely wrong.

-It takes so long to get the answer, supposing that our net its already trained.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

chat = ChatBot('luis')

# Create a new trainer for the chatbot
train = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chat)

# Train the chatbot based on the spanish corpus
# C:\Users\mcarvajalr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Chatterbot\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot_corpus\data\spanish
train.train("chatterbot.corpus.spanish.trivia",
            "chatterbot.corpus.spanish.greetings",
            "chatterbot.corpus.spanish.DesbloqueoAD_rev03")

conversa = [
    "Quien es pacman",
    "Es una fantasma"
]

train = ListTrainer(chat)
train.train(conversa)

# Get a response to an input statement
chat.get_response("pacman ")
chat.get_response("desbloqueo cuenta")
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some code of how you use the library. These questions are too vague to give you a clear answer. There could be many different issues.

Comment: Sorry, thought I've added it, now I did it, thanks for the comment.